# Intent detects regex entity

Tags: dialogflow-es

Since regexp entities are available, I added one to my agent.
This entity is used as a required parameter of my intent.
After some tests it seems to not detect my intent using a word matching the regexp.
Any idea ?

**IE** :

**Intent Training phrase**: "my car is registered aa123aa"

"aa123aa" is the resolved value of a parameter of type regNum entity.

**Entity regNum** : ^[a-hj-np-tv-z]{2}(?:\s|-)?[0-9]{3}(?:\s|-)?[a-hj-np-tv-z]{2}$

I expect that the following phrase should match the intent and resolve the parameter value :
"my car is registered bb123bb"

In fact it matchs the intent but it's unable to resolve the parameter value.

Moreover if I use the training phrase "my car is registered aa123aa" it does not resolves the parameter value either

Comment: Can you show us more of the setup that you are using for this intent. Normally adding entities won't trigger a specific intent. Have you added a phrase to trigger the intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogflow uses re2 regex. for more information visit this [repository](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

For example:

`ABc1234@` is equivalent to
 `\A([A-Z]{2}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{4}[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]{1})\z`

`\A` - beginning of text 
`[A-Z]{2}` - two uppercase letter A-Z 
 `[a-z]{1}` - one lowercase letter a-z 
 `[0-9]{4}` - four numbers 
 `[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]{1}` - one special character. 
`\z` - end of text

Comment: Thanks for the information, it will probably be useful for me to know that Dialogflow uses re2

Comment: I solved the issue using your answer, the mistake was to use \A & \z in my regexp, so it can't match it in a phrase.

Comment: what should be the regex format if we can use ***either*** upper case or lower case alphabets for the initial 3 letters?